# Integrate MyBB with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, mybb

I am integrating mybb forum for website developed in codeigniter. I check model provided here 
https://github.com/bcit-ci/codeigniter-website/blob/master/application/models/Mybb.php 
But i am not getting how can I start with it. If we download and installing mybb in our project and it already have script to register user and other things so if i want to register user for mybb automatically when get register to website do I need to write separate code?

Comment: copy and paste your code here instead of providing external link

Comment: It is whole github repository.

Comment: I am just using model link i mention, I download and check that repository it does not have any mybb installation folder